# Pickling/Unpickling vs Reading/Writing from txt - Memory Efficiency

Tags: python, memory, pickle

Recently I've been interested in optimizing data processing for a project where I send many API requests. Instead of saving the responses directly in console (ie. writing to a list), I instead write the returned data to a pickle file. It's my understanding that this is more efficient when considering memory limitations. However, I load the data back in, and noticed a significant amount of memory being used up. After some research, it looks like unpickled object is getting stored in memory and takes up a considerable amount of space. So instead of pickling/unpickling, would writing to a json/txt file be more efficient? Would really appreciate some technical guidance on this.

Comment: pickling writes to a file just like json/txt file writing, with some small differences. Regardless, you'll probably end up loading the file into memory either way. You could compare the two to see if there are differences in performance... If needed, you could read a file in chunks to conserve memory.

Comment: @JacobIRR There can still be massive differences in *how* the data is loaded into memory, though. [Demo](https://tio.run/##jY0xDsIwDEX3nMJjkqFqxcLCSRCqTBJBRNxYiTv09CFQJMSGp/9lv2fe5J6Xw5FLa5E4FwGO7pGC@jQp6AJhStkBVhBSSmiogkW0UQgnOE@jtdPY5wIWXkFxiYvofncLMr8NfqZAuWzamJ3P3HFVO7//G/xKXDWaH//1u08ZfdXV/Ctv7Qk) of the original data taking just 12 KB and the unpickled data taking 4.4 MB.

Comment: Your description is pretty vague. It's unclear what you did, what/how you measured, and how much space was taken.